# Replace beginning and end of delimiters separately using regex

Tags: regex, r

I want to replace the `$` delimiters in the following expression.

```
s <- "something before stuff $some text$ in between $1$ and after"
```

The replacement at the beginning and at the end has to be different, i.e.

```
begin <- "<B>"     # replacement for 1st delimiter   
end <- "<E>"       # replacement for 2nd delimiter
```

The result should be

```
str_replace_all(s, SOME-REGEX-MAGIC)    
> [1] "something before stuff <B>some text<E> in between <B>1<E> and after"
```

I am not an regex pro and was not able to figure out how to address the beginning and end of the delimiter separately.

Any ideas? Thanks for your time!

**Non-successful ideas**

Just for the records my totally unsuccessful ideas to get closer to a solution:

```
# Using lookarounds I get the following, but I would need it to be non-greedy
str_extract(s, perl("(?<=\\$).*(?=\\$)"))
"some text$ and some more $1"

# also greedy
str_match(s, "(\\$)(.*)(\\$)")
     [,1]                            [,2] [,3]                          [,4]
[1,] "$some text$ and some more $1$" "$"  "some text$ and some more $1" "$"
```

Comment: Did you try to simply remove the `$`?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte. What do you mean exactly? I want to replace them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regular expression with `gsub()`.  The replacement makes use of back references (e.g. `\\1`).

```
ptn <- "\\$(.*?)\\$" # Non-greedy find between delimiters
replacement <- "<B>\\1<E>"  # \\1 indicates back-reference
gsub(ptn, replacement, s)
[1] "something before stuff <B>some text<E> in between <B>1<E> and after"
```

The back reference `\\1` indicates the first wild-card expression in the regex -- i.e. the string inside the parens -- `(.*?)`.  The `?` modifier makes the match non-greedy.

Comment: Wow. simpler than I thought! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use the non-greedy operator `?`

```
\\$(.*?)\\$
```

or

```
\\$([^$]*)\\$
```